# Why my LSTM for Multi-Label Text Classification underperforms?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm, text-classification

I'm using Windows 10 machine.
Libraries: Keras with Tensorflow 2.0
Embeddings:Glove(100 dimensions)

I am trying to implement an LSTM architecture for multi-label text classification.

My problem is that no matter how much fine-tuning I do, the results are really bad.

I am not experienced in DL practical implementations that's why I ask for your advice.

Below I will state basic information about my dataset and my model so far.

**I can't embed images since I am a new member so they appear as links.**

[Dataset form+Embedings form+train-test-split form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/042Xw.png)

[Dataset's labels distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVnTV.png)

[My Implementation of LSTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/114rf.png)

[Model's Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgbwA.png)

[Model's Accuracy plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaS2e.png)

[Model's Loss plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf0Ql.png)

As you can see my dataset is really small (~6.000 examples) and maybe that's one reason why I cannot achieve better results. Still, I chose it because it's unbiased.

1. I'd like to know if there is any fundamental mistake in my code regarding the dimensions, shape, activation functions, and loss functions for multi-label text classification?
2. What would you recommend to achieve better results on my model? Also any general advice regarding optimizing, methods,# of nodes, layers, dropouts, etc is very welcome.

Model's best val accuracy that I achieved so far is ~0.54 and even if I tried to raise it, it seems stuck there.

Comment: is it safe to assume you are using sigmoid activation on the final layer with binary cross-entropy loss?

Comment: Exactly. Sigmoid and binary cross-entropy since its a multi-label classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to get this wrong but the most common mistake is to get your model overfit the training data.
I suspect that 0.54 accuracy means that your model selects the most common label (offensive) for almost all cases.

So, consider one of these simple solutions:

- Create balanced training data: like 400 samples from each class.
- or sample balanced batches for training (exactly the same number of labels on each training batch)

In addition to tracking accuracy and loss, look at precision-recall-f1 or even better try plotting area under curve, maybe different classes need different thresholds of activation. (If you are using Sigmoid on last layer maybe one class could perform better with 0.2 activations and another class with 0.7)

Comment: Great suggestions! I tried to use balanced batches in Keras through this library "from keras_balanced_batch_generator import make_generator". First, I transformed my X & y to numpy.ndarray because it's a requirement for the library. I implemented it like this: " generator = make_generator(X, y, batch_size=32)
history = model_LSTM.fit(generator, epochs=30,callbacks=[early_stopping])" But i get an error saying: "ValueError: Args `x` and `y` must have the same length." My shapes of X and y are: X_shape: (5647,) y_shape: (5647, 6)" how can they have the same shape I don't get how this works.

Comment: Also since I'm new, maybe the comment above should I integrate into my main post? Not sure what is the proper way.

Comment: yes edit the question as much as you want as far as it improves the question for future you and others.

Comment: great, can you maybe help me with the comment above? How to tackle it?

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting this error. perhaps this is a keras error. check the version of the keras you are using?

Answer (score 0):

1. first try simple model.  embedding 1 layer LSTM than classify
2. how to tokenize text , is vocab size enough ?
3. try dice loss